# Letting the user to choose the name for object

Tags: c#

Here's the relevant part from my code:

```
        //Allow user to add details of a player
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a player name");
        string player = Console.ReadLine();

        //Create new player object
        PlayersClass userPlayer = new PlayersClass();
```

And that's my PlayersClass:

```
    class PlayersClass
    {
        public int id;
        public string name, city, street, teamName;
        public DateTime birthDate;
        public float height;
    }
```

I want the player object to be named after the user input - player (the string).
Instead of userPlayer i want the value of the string player.

Is it possible in c#?

*Further detail:*
It's going to get into a list of players which contains objects named after the players names. Only in this specific part of code i want the user to enter just one player's details. You see, the whole list of players are already made of objects named after player names (ignore the property name inside the class just in this case)

Comment: No, you don't really want that. I think what you want is simply to set the `name` property of the player object to the string you entered. Then you can use that for display etc. I assume you are probably going to ask for other details like birth date etc in the same way too. Renaming your variable would serve no purpose at all (and it's not possible, anyway - variable names are set when you compile the code, not when you run it).

Comment: No, i want the object itself to be named after the user input's name. Is it possible? i know there's a lot of room for mistakes that way but i need it for this specific project.

Comment: " i want the object itself to be named after the user input's name"...I really doubt it.  Why do you think you want that? How is it going to help anything? The user will never see it.

Comment: " but i need it for this specific project" Why do you need it for your project? Which problem do you want to solve by this?

Comment: Also, use Properties, not Fields.

Comment: _"i know there's a lot of room for mistakes that way but i need it for this specific project"_ ...no, there's no room for mistakes because it's not even possible, as I've already explained. Is this some homework or something? Perhaps you've misunderstood the instructions. If you tell us specifically what instructions you've been given, maybe we can help you to interpret them.

Comment: Maybe you want to store your variable in a `Dictionary<string,PlayerClass>`. Then you can use the user input as a key.

Comment: Because it's going to get into a list of players which contains objects named after the players names. Only in this specific part of code i want the user to enter just one player's details. You see, the whole list of players are already made of objects named after player names (ignore the property name inside the class just in this case)

Comment: That would make a lot more sense. But it isn't what you asked for. And for that you don't need to rename the variable itself, all you need to do is create a list which enables you to use a key to identify each entry in the list. A Dictionary is a good structure for doing that, as has just been mentioned above. You can set the key to be the entered text, and associate it with the player object (regardless of the name of the variable which first contained the object).

Comment: @roiguber: Then you have *one list* (no matter whether that's a `List<PlayersClass>`, an array (`PlayersClass[]`), or anything else) with player objects inside, and the individual player objects have *no name*, because there are no individual variables pointing to them.

Comment: I dont understand how to use dictionary for that cause, can some one please share an example?

Comment: I added your last comment (about lists) to the main text of the question, because it's vital to understanding what you really want. You can see below that someone has added an answer showing how you can use a dictionary.

Comment: `You see, the whole list of players are already made of objects named after player names (ignore the property name inside the class just in this case)` what. Why ignore? That's a critical thing for you here.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl only for my case, not for the whole code purpose

Comment: _"the whole list of players are already made of objects named after player names"_ ...can you show how you did that exactly? I suspect that, in actual fact, the names of the variables would end up being irrelevant. If you aren't using a dictionary already, then you won't be able to use those variable names to retrieve the data later, which makes it pointless to even start like that. You'd only be able to identify them if you also set the "name" property _inside_ the object, which could then be queried.

Comment: @ADyson thank you it works with dictionary and i have accepted the answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended above in the comments, you can use a dictionary to store your instances by name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class PlayersClass
{
    public int id;
    public string name, city, street, teamName;
    public DateTime birthDate;
    public float height;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, PlayersClass> players = new Dictionary<string, PlayersClass>();
        string player = "bob"; //Console.ReadLine();
        players[player] = new PlayersClass(){ 
          name = player
        };
        player = "justin"; //Console.ReadLine();
        players[player] = new PlayersClass() {
          name = player
        };
        Console.WriteLine(players["justin"].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @roiguber; you did not know how to use Dictionaries, and in less than 2 minutes you've verified this code does what you want and it now works? damn, you're fast. Just be careful: Dictionaries doesn't like being asked for items that they don't know. `var playerObject = players["ksjadhkjlhlasdkjfasld"]` will likely throw an exception.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, noted. BTW, somebody already formatted said lines. I did not notice when I pasted directly from dotnetfiddle.